# c# EMULATOR - WIFI

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Is there an alternative to test the WIFI environment? The c# windows mobile EMULATOR does not have radio abilities. I don't have a windows mobile phone. What should I do? Isn't there any other alternative?

Comment: Linked to question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007456/c-wifi-discovery/5007499#5007499

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The radio stack and how the driver supports the hardware varies widely from device to device.  I flat out wouldn't trust any emulation of WiFi under WinMo 6.x or ealier.  You must test on a physical device, and I'd highly recommend that you test on the actual hardware you're targeting.  The only thing more troublesome than WiFi on pre-Phone Windows Mobile was dealing with power states.

Answer (score 0):

There are communities wiling to test beta software. Find a windows mobile one, they have phones

Comment: I am working on windows XP and visual studio 2008. Can you plese send me a link for that time of virtual phone?